# MSVC++ 17 std::copy expects "operator -" for custom iterator

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I migrate my project from VC++ 2015 to VC++ 2017.
I have my own implementation of iterator. It has forward-only operations set:

```
template <class Container>
struct NodeTableIterator
{
    typedef NodeTableIterator<Container> this_t;
    this_t& operator ++();
    this_t operator ++(int);
};
```

Somewhere in code I use it for `std::copy`

```
std::copy(tbl.begin(), tbl.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
```

This line perfectly worked in VC++2015 but fails in 2017 just because:

> error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const NodeTableIterator...'

Simple inspection inside `std::copy` shows this source of error:

```
    const auto _UDest = _Unchecked_n(_Dest, _Idl_distance<_InIt>(_UFirst, _ULast));
```

Where _Idl_distance really expects that my iterator should support `operator -`. 
Have you any idea how to overcome this strange requirement?

Comment: Why can't you implement that operator in your iterator class?

Comment: Does your iterator define the required `iterator_category` member type to be `std::forward_iterator_tag`? The error contains the template typename `_RanIt` in the error message, which sounds like `std::copy` is treating your iterator like a random-access iterator -- which could be due to bad iterator deduction.

Comment: @vahancho - because it is neither semantically nor physically defined. For example you have hash-table with buckets, 2 iterators points onto separate buckets, what the meaning of subtraction between them?

Comment: @Dewfy, maybe the distance between two buckets? In other words, it will define how many steps you need to move from one bucket to another.

Comment: @vahancho fictive distance for senseless operation that expects extra development effort. No thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide the five types, either within the class itself:

```
template <class Container>
struct NodeTableIterator {
    using iterator_category = /* ... */;
    using value_type = /* ... */;
    using difference_type = /* ... */;
    using pointer = /* ... */;
    using reference = /* ... */;
    // ...
};
```

or within a custom specialization of `std::iterator_traits`.  Otherwise, the tag dispatch on the iterator category in the standard algorithms won't work.

---

Reference: [[iterator.traits]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/iterator.traits#1) (the types in `std::iterator_traits` are required to be present)

> To implement algorithms only in terms of iterators, it is often
>   necessary to determine the value and difference types that correspond
>   to a particular iterator type. Accordingly, it is required that if
>   `Iterator` is the type of an iterator, the types
>
> ```
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category
> ```
>
> be defined as the iterator's difference type, value type and iterator
>   category, respectively. In addition, the types
>
> ```
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer
> ```
>
> shall be defined as the iterator's reference and pointer types, that
>   is, for an iterator object `a`, the same type as the type of `*a` and
>   `a->`, respectively. In the case of an output iterator, the types
>
> ```
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer
> ```
>
> may be defined as `void`.

[[iterator.traits]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/iterator.traits#2) (the types in `std::iterator_traits` can be generated from the member types)

> If `Iterator` has valid ([temp.deduct]) member types
>   `difference_­type`, `value_­type`, `pointer`, `reference`, and
>   `iterator_­category`, `iterator_­traits<Iterator>` shall have the
>   following as publicly accessible members:
>
> ```
> using difference_type   = typename Iterator::difference_type;
> using value_type        = typename Iterator::value_type;
> using pointer           = typename Iterator::pointer;
> using reference         = typename Iterator::reference;
> using iterator_category = typename Iterator::iterator_category;
> ```
>
> Otherwise, `iterator_­traits<Iterator>` shall have no members by any
>   of the above names.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to define `NodeTableIterator::iterator_category`. More specifically, it must not be  `std::random_access_iterator_tag` or else `operator-` will be required by the algorithm.

You also need to define

```
NodeTableIterator::difference_type
NodeTableIterator::value_type
NodeTableIterator::pointer
NodeTableIterator::reference
```

Or else `std::iterator_traits` won't have any of those definitions. Or you can spesialise `std::iterator_traits` explicitly. Note that if you don't do either of these things, then `NodeTableIterator` is not an `Iterator` at all.

Comment: There should be no need to specialize `iterator_traits`. Custom iterators in C++17 just need to have the appropriate member types defined.